# Php Check If a Static Class is Declared

Tags: php, object, static

How can i check to see if a static class has been declared?
ex
Given the class

```
class bob {
    function yippie() {
        echo "skippie";
    }
}
```

later in code how do i check:

```
if(is_a_valid_static_object(bob)) {
    bob::yippie();
}
```

so i don't get:
Fatal error: Class 'bob' not found in file.php on line 3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also check for existence of a specific method, even without instantiating the class

```
echo method_exists( bob, 'yippie' ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

If you want to go one step further and verify that "yippie" is actually static, use the [Reflection API](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.reflection) (PHP5 only)

```
try {
    $method = new ReflectionMethod( 'bob::yippie' );
    if ( $method->isStatic() )
    {
        // verified that bob::yippie is defined AND static, proceed
    }
}
catch ( ReflectionException $e )
{
    //  method does not exist
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

or, you could combine the two approaches

```
if ( method_exists( bob, 'yippie' ) )
{
    $method = new ReflectionMethod( 'bob::yippie' );
    if ( $method->isStatic() )
    {
        // verified that bob::yippie is defined AND static, proceed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[`bool class_exists( string $class_name [, bool $autoload  ]`)](https://www.php.net/class_exists)

> This function checks whether or not the given class has been defined.