# How can I get PHP reflection to tell me if a class method is static or not?

Tags: php, reflection, static-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php Check If a Static Class is Declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123718/php-check-if-a-static-class-is-declared)

Given this class:

```
class TestClass {

    public function displayNormal() {
        return 'test';
    }

    public static function displayStatic() {
        return 'test';
    }

}
```

I reflect on it with this code:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('TestClass');
$methods = $reflector->getMethods();
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    qdev::showArray($method, __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

which gives me an array of data about its methods:

```
name: displayAsDocumentation
class: DqlItems

name: displayAsDocumentationSTATIC
class: DqlItems
```

However, from this information, I can't tell if a method is static or not.

**What do I have to change to way I reflect on the object so that it tells me if a class method is static or not?**

Answer (score 3):

[ReflectionMethod::isStatic](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.isstatic.php)